# Have my particles let trail of there movement on the scene in SpriteKit even in a child node

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, particles, skemitternode

I want the same effect than [in this project](https://github.com/neilang/SpriteKit-TrackingMissileExample-iOS)

But my particles `SKEmitterNode` isn't directly in the Scene, but in a child node.
My particles are reactor effect behind my spaceship, and I want it to leave a trail on the scene as the SpaceShip node moves.

Right now my particles are a child node of my SpaceShip and so, "all" particles move with the SpaceShip so it display just a point and doesn't leave a trail.

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the `targetNode` on your emitter to be your `SKScene`.

Comment: Couldn't ask for a better answer, you sir is the real MVP :)

Answer (score 0):

I am using this one to make a trail behind a ship in swift by SKEmitterNode.`

```
sparkEmmiter.targetNode = self.scene
```

Where sparkEmmiter is a object of SKEmitterNode. and make it to child of the ship.

```
ship.addChild(sparkEmmiter)
```

Where ship is SKSpriteNode object.